# Capturing logs using adb?

Tags: adb

Does anyone know how to capture logs either using adb logcat or bugreport on a locked android device ?

It works on unlocked device using the command
Adb logcat <file.txt>

Comment: What type of "Locked" are you talking about? Locked after reboot before first user authentication or just a regular locked device (lock screen). adb should work without any changes if it is just the lock screen.

Comment: Not a regular lock screen but after using the following command on a device to lock.   adb reboot bootloader and then  fastboot flashing lock